# Cant change source on ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

(ive edited codes to a test app)

first of all, Im sorry for my bad english.

I try to change the picture "euroeins" to "eurozwei" with Method "eurozweichange".
Picture is on main_activity.xml id=iveuro
Button to change on optionspage.xml id=imageButton8

Now my Problem: My problem is "changing" the "source file" of a "ImageView" with a "Method".

I currently code on API 19, caused by my slow Internet connection. (Only have API 19).

LogCat says 20 and more "AndroidRuntime" errors with different textes. App exits when i click on button "imageButton8" with message "Unfortunately, TestApp has stopped." (added LogCat at bottom)

I tryed every code in this Forum and almost every code on every page on big-g. But even get the same errors.

My source files are in /res/drawale-hdpi

Picture i wanna change 
xml "activity_main":

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testproject.MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibbuttonoptions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:src="@drawable/optionsbutton"
    android:onClick="button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iveuro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/euroeins" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2nd xml layout "optionspage":

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testproject.MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:onClick="eurozweichange"
        android:src="@drawable/eurozweismall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main class
"MainActivity.java"

```
package com.example.testproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void button (View view) 
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.optionspage);
    }


    public void backtomain (View view)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void eurozweichange (View view)
    {
        ImageView picturetochange = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iveuro);
        picturetochange.setImageResource(R.drawable.eurozwei);
    }
}
```

I also tryed Bitmap and BitmapFactory.decodeResource.() and almost all on stackoverflow ;) Same.

Something else you need to know?

greets wetfoxx

log is here:
03-04 03:04:52.296: W/dalvikvm(1481): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0568ba8)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Process: com.example.testproject, PID: 1481
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     ... 11 more
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.example.testproject.MainActivity.eurozweichange(MainActivity.java:62)
03-04 03:04:52.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     ... 14 more

Comment: post your logcat output or errors here.

Comment: Done it. And edited code to sample app. I tryed to change visibility on 2 ImageView too (iveuroeins and iveurozwei) . Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...

the Method needs to be:

```
public void eurozweichange (View view) 
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //this was missing
                //i think it wont work because layout with ID was not loaded.
    ImageView picturetochange= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iveuro);
    picturetochange.setImageResource(R.drawable.eurozwei);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your code properly you have written `android:onClick="changepic"`, but your method name is `eurozweichange(View view)`. keep both name same.

either edit your ImageButtom

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:src="@drawable/pictwosmall"
    android:onClick="eurozweichange" />
```

or change method name

```
public void changepic (View view) {
    ImageView picturetochange= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainpic);
    picturetochange.setImageResource(R.drawable.pictwo);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: that was not the problem. i edited to other code with same problem.

Comment: I found the solution. Your answer was indirect right.

Answer (score 0):

The Main problem is in clickLisner,  I think you are using Fragment so please remove OnClick from xml file, You are setting image Right way 
Just need to change clickLisner like as

```
  ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
    tvregister1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            eurozweichange(view);
        }
    });
```